# How to choose a value from another table using a JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I just want to know one SQL query.

I've got two tables:

```
id | id_town
1  | 26



id | town
26 | Prague
```

What's the query if I need to print "Prague"?
Thank you.

PhpMyAdmin prints **#1052 - Column 'id' in on clause is ambiguous**

I tried this

```
SELECT town FROM localities JOIN towns ON id = id_town
```

Comment: try GOOGLE its a really useful learning aid http://www.sql-join.com/

Comment: Alternatively show us the query you have tried, as we love a tryer. And we can then help you

Comment: select ft.town from first_table ft left join second_table st on st.id = ft.id_town where ft.id_town = 26

Comment: Please go through mysql basic learning before coming out here.

Comment: @RadekHomola : He specified he is getting error with id being ambiguous & You still wrote I guess same query he might have tried ;)

Comment: You do not have a column called `id_town` you cannot just invent column names in a query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133265/discussion-between-v-for-vendetta-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: Error message is pretty clear. Id column is present in both the tables use Alias name to differentiate

Comment: `SELECT town FROM localities l JOIN towns t ON t.id = l.id_town`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS:

```
select b.town
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.id_town = b.id
```

Comment: When you answer question for people that dont appear to have done anything but ask for us to write code for them, you just encourage more **Do it for me** questions

Comment: Sorry sir, as on my understanding he is suffering from that issue is because of Alias that we know but bit difficult for him. Still may I delete my answer ?

Comment: @Suraz At least give him a try on his own instead of spoon feeding.

Comment: Accepted my dear friends